# Convert "12:37:37.641 UTC Tue Apr 5 2016" date format into datatime in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert "12:37:37.641 UTC Tue Apr 5 2016" this string into DateTime in sql server 2008. Can anyone help me to convert this.

Comment: This is no datetime format I had to deal with before... Are the day and month names of 3 characters length always? Is this something you need fast and "everywhere" or is this a one time action?

Comment: Actually, the system sent us the data in mentioned format, we need to convert this data into dateTime. Do you know any way to convert it into SQL standard format?

Comment: I just posted an answer. If the string lenghts might vary one could try to set the `22` in my answer dynamically by searching for "UTC" and the following spaces. If it's always the same, it's easier of course...

Comment: Be carefull and check, if really *all* your rows have "UTC". If not you must consider time shifts...

Comment: @Shnugo your given solution is working for me. Thank you for your quick response and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try it like this:

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(100)='12:37:37.641 UTC Tue Apr 5 2016';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@d,22,1000) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@d,1,12),109);
```

The result

```
2016-04-05 12:37:37.640
```